# linebreaks filter not working in Django template

Tags: python, html, django

I have a simple? problem. I am editing my html template to include the linebreaks function into django. However, when using a value such as 'Hello \n World' what returns is exactly Hello \n World. Aka the filter is not replacing the \n.

```html
</script> <!-- End of javascript -->

<head>

<body>

<div id="container">

    <h2> GREEn Quiz 
         Survey Question {{q.snum}} </h2>
<!-- It appears that {{q.snum}} isn't being used-->

<div class="question">

    <span id = qspan>
    {{surv.text}}
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id = m_info>
    {{'Hello \n World'|linebreaks}}
    </span>

</div> 



<div id="ready_set_go" class "gq">

</div>

<div id="Back_Button" class "Back">

</div>

<div id="debug" data-gameid="{{g.id}}"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the output

```html
<p>Hello \n World</p>
```

Comment: Does using `linebreaksbr` make a difference?

Comment: The output no longer has paragraph breaks , but that's it.

Comment: Try surrounding the block with `{% autoescape off %} ... {% endautoescape %}`. This should ensure that the html renders appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

@SustainRayne in this case you can create a custom tag like:

```
@register.filter(name="multiline_break")
@stringfilter
def multiline_break(value):
    return mark_safe(value.replace("\\n", "<br>"))
```